# Promote Method returned an invalid Value for the Distributed transaction error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have just deployed my ASP.NET web API application to Azure app services. I get this error when saving to db:

> Promote Method returned an invalid Value for the Distributed
>   transaction

This is the way I create and open the connection:

```
            var connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            connection.Open();
```

but if I comment out the `connection.Open();`, I no longer get that error. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that your transactions are being promoted to a distributed transaction. As far as i know, DCOM is not supported in the Azure WebApp (may be wrong, but it looks like the issue is still here). 
Do you open the multiple sqlconnections in the scope?

Comment: thanks for the help. it happens during nested transactions and/or sqlconnections.. but like i mentioned, the problem goes away if i comment out connection.Open(); which makes me worry should there be any repercussions

Comment: Ah, ok. That is why - if you open a lot of connections inside of one transaction scope it can be elevated. Could you try to use SQLTransaction?  I saw the ENLIST=FALSE in connection string, but did not try it by myself. I am not sure if that is OK for production, but could you please try it as a testing effort? If that will not help, let's troubleshoot further.